# How to apply django patches

Tags: django

I want to apply a patch to this bug (http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13095) but I have never done it before and I have no idea where to begin. Can anyone point me to a tutorial?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On Linux/UNIX, you can use the `patch` command for this.

It works in the following way:

```
cd /usr/lib.../site-packages/django/
patch --dry-run -p1 < ~/downloads/somefix.patch
```

The patch command looks in the file to find the proper files it needs to update.
The `-p1` tells patch to ignore the first level of the folder mentioned in the patch file. Often this is the project name itself. The `--dry-run` option prevents actual execution, so you can experiment with it.

When everything is allright, you can remove the `--dry-run` option, and the actual patch will be applied.

---

On Windows, several tools (e.g. WinMerge / TortoiseMerge) have a "Apply patch" option in the menu, which will allow you to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try 'patch' if you are using a linux based server.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28Unix%29

Windows appears do have a utility written for it although I havent used one

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm

remember to make backups of the directory if you are unsure of its outcome