# Add button for Django inlines not present after upgrade from 1.4 to 1.5

Tags: django, django-admin

On Django 1.4 i had tabular inlines which had the add button to add more rows, but upon what I thought was a successful upgrade to 1.5, this functionality no longer exists!

The following is my code, very basic, and nothing has changed during the upgrade!

```
class modelInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = vehicleModel
    extra = 3

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return True

class codeInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = vehicleCode
    extra = 3

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return True


class CarAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['name',  'description', 'country']
    inlines = [modelInline]

class VehicleModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ['carManufacturer','model']
    inlines = [codeInline]
```

All my admin files are sitting in my static files folder, I've had a look at inlines.js but being pretty new to this I don't quite understand what is happening.

Comment: what do you mean by "functionality does not exist" ? Is it throwing any errors, or is it not displaying the widgets ?

Comment: It is not displaying the add button in my inline after the upgrade to Django 1.5. No errors are being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the ticket detailign this issue:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13023

The patch which resolves the issue :
https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/13023/13023_inlines_patch.diff

Comment: Thanks for that I have recently found this as well, but being quite to new to almost everything django related, how to I go about using or "patching" with this information?

Comment: This should help you patch the fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331411/how-to-apply-django-patches